# Unable to create a servlet in heroku project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, servlets, heroku, eclipse-plugin

I started using the **Heroku plugin for Eclipse**.I created a Heroku project in my Eclipse Juno 4.2.I selected the **jetty** framework template from the list of available templates in Heroku.

Now when i try to create a new Servlet for my Heroku project i do not see the name of my project in the select project drop down box.I faced a similar problem when i tried to create a project using Google App Engine plugin.

I want to create a web application which has Two Servlets and several RESTFUL WebServices which i want to create using Jersey API.I am able to create these very easily for Dynamic Web Project.

Is there a way to do it using the Heroku Project for Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the ***New Servlet Wizard*** in Eclipse, the project you are trying to select must be a webtools faceted project (created by Dynamic Web project wizard).  It can't be added to normal java projects.  You can convert an existing project to a faceted web project by right clicking and selected ***Project facets*** and clicking the ***Convert to faceted form*** link.  Then selecting the ***Dynamic web module*** facet.  Then click the ***Further configuration available*** to select docroot, etc.

Comment: SO if i convert my heroku project to dynamic web module would i still be able to deploy it to heroku ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Heroku projects but I don't see why not.  A faceted project that sets the web module facet doesn't change any source files, it just adds some settings under the .settings/ folder.  Its eclipse metadata that tells the rest of Eclipse that your project is a "web" project.  Thus the new servlet wizard will list that project in the dropdown.